# Getting Data from a Combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, data-retrieval

I'm new to forms in access, so I apologize for asking about something that is probably simple.
I am trying to get the chosen value from a combo drop-down into another table. But I am having trouble retrieving the data. I even tried something as simple as just putting it into a message box. After looking up on line I came up with:

```
Private Sub Combo()
    MsgBox Me.Combo.Column(0)
End Sub
```

All I get is invalid use of Me Keyword.
The Combo's name has been changed to Combo in properties. The values come from table4 (column1)
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the same exact code you have listed above `MsgBox Me.Combo.Column(1)`  Something is wrong with one of the following:

1. Your control is not named `Combo`
2. You do not have a value picked in the combobox
3. Or you record source for the combobox is not returning any results.

Please post the combobox recordsource.  If you provide more information, I can assist you better but those are the most common problems with invalid use of null with comboboxs

**EDIT**

I noticed in your code that you have `Me.Combo.Column(1)` and it should be `Me.Combo.Column(0)` since you only have 1 column it is a zero based index.  Additionally, I would create that code within the vba for that form.  If you click on that combo-> properties-> event tab-> Afterupdate -> ... -> codebuilder and add your code there, it will do whatever after you update the combo box.

Comment: 1. The name is definitely Combo - under name in property sheet.

Comment: @user2632074 Can you post the access db someone so I can take a look at it?

Comment: 3. Under "Record Source" I have SELECT [4].Result FROM 4; for the form. This has a field called results with 3 values: Pass, Fail, Minor

Comment: 2. I added a macro to show a pop-up whenever I chose something from the list, so I'm sure that a value was picked.

Comment: @user2632074 I have a feeling that you are having a problem with your sql statement.  Create a new query and paste your query into it and click view datasheet.  If you get no results or it wont run that is your problem.

Comment: Using the query builder for the form, I get back the table with my 3 options.

Comment: I am at a loss without have access to the access file or more of the code.

Comment: I won't be able to upload it anywhere today. Will do it tomorrow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would remove all those comments with links.  There is an x next to the word ago in the comment.  Click it and it will delete them.  Also I have added an edit to the answer that should fix your problem.

Comment: @user2632074 please mark the answer as correct if it answered your question.

Comment: So I now have this code on the same form on a button to update the values into a new table:
'Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Dim a, b As String
    a = Me.Combo.Column(0)
    b = Me.Combo4.Column(0)
    MsgBox a & ", " & b
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Table1](Field 1) values ('" & Me.Combo.Column(0) & "', '" & Me.Combo4.Column(0) & "')"
End Sub
I keep getting a syntax error on the sql.'

Comment: @user2632074 Four things, 1. You should start a new question for question that differ from the original question. 2. Since the first question was answered please mark it answered. 3. in your statement fields with spaced in it must have [] around it like `([Field 1])`. 4. You are trying to insert two values when you are only specifing 1 which is field 1. If you want to insert two use `"INSERT INTO [Table1]([Field 1],[Field 2]) values ('" & Me.Combo.Column(0) & "', '" & Me.Combo4.Column(0) & "')"`

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had two fields, because I started with two, went down to one and added in for the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are writing the code inside the form where your comboBox is placed
and also try for this

```
MsgBox Me.Combo.Column(0,1)
```